# Wordpress $wpdb query issue

Tags: counter, wordpress

I am making a custom counter as a wordpress plugin and I hav a little problem with $wpdb
This is the query that fails:

```
private function getMedlemmerfromDB(){
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $wpdb->plugin_medlemsteller = $table_prefix . "plugin_medlemsteller";
    $fromdb=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT medlemmer FROM $wpdb->plugin_medlemsteller WHERE mID=(SELECT MAX(mID) FROM $wpdb->plugin_medlemsteller)");
    return $fromdb;
}
```

i do not know what $table_prefix is set to. just hoping it's empty.

in my widget function:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $medlemmer=getMedlemmerfromDB();
             ...
```

This fails, and the plugin (witch is still active) doesn't show.

The query works fine, but when I implement it in my plugin it causes the widget to crash.

Hope some one can help me out.

-Krister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
$medlemmer=getMedlemmerfromDB();
```

with

```
$medlemmer=$this->getMedlemmerfromDB();
```

if `widget()` and `getMedlemmerfromDB()` are methods of the same class.

Comment: ok great it worked out for you and good luck with your plugin (it's good karma to vote/accept any helpful answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `$wpdb->plugin_medlemsteller`. Only default WordPress tables can be accessed like that.

You need to define it first:

```
$wpdb->plugin_medlemsteller = $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_medlemsteller";
```

Comment: so if I do it in a function like this:
[code] private function getMedlemmerfromDB(){
  global $wpdb;
  $plugin_medlemsteller = $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_medlemsteller";
  $fromdb=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT medlemmer FROM $plugin_medlemsteller WHERE mID=(SELECT MAX(mID) FROM plugin_medlemsteller)");
  return $fromdb;
 }[/code]